# How to escape auto-completed brackets in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I jump out of a set of auto-completed brackets in Eclipse?

For instance if I open a set of parenthesis I can jump out of that set by hitting the tab key.

For example: `if (x <= y)|`

- If I hit the tab key while inside of the (), my cursor will jump to the position of the |.

Whenever I make new brackets for a class, if-else, etc, it becomes annoying always having to hit the arrow key to get out of the brackets.

For example: `if (x <= y) 
              {
                  *code*
              }`

- Is there a way to jump to the outside of the braces, besides having to use the arrow keys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not with one command afaik, but you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to jump to the closing bracket `}` and then use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to jump to a new line inserted after the closing bracket.

Comment: Hmm that only worked if my cursor was next to the beginning bracket `{`|. Then I could CTRL + Shift + P to jump to the end of `}`